# rsync the info to a file

Tags: shell-script, rsync

I use rsync to backup my data from one server to the other.  This works great.

```
rsync -aktvu -e 'ssh -p 22' --modify-window=1 --progress $SOURCE $USER@$SERVER:$DESTINATION
```

The output display what has been copied over:

```
building file list ...
11 files to consider
./
server/

server/myfile.txt
        3152 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=8/11)
server/test/
server/test/logfile01
        8266 100%    7.88MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=6/11)
server/test/logfile07
       41004 100%   39.10MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=5/11)
server/test/logfile08
         318 100%  310.55kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#4, to-check=4/11)
server/test/logfile09
        8262 100%    7.88MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#5, to-check=3/11)
server/test/logfile30
       40325 100%   12.82MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#6, to-check=2/11)
server/test/logfile31
         792 100%  193.36kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#7, to-check=1/11)
server/test/logfile32
        3152 100%  769.53kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#8, to-check=0/11)

sent 105902 bytes  received 214 bytes  14148.80 bytes/sec
total size is 105271  speedup is 0.99
```

I would like to get this output and save it to a file for reference.  So I tried this,

```
test_output=$(rsync -aktvu -e 'ssh -p 22' --modify-window=1 --progress $SOURCE $USER@$SERVER:$DESTINATION)

getscript() {
   pgrep -lf ".[ /]$1( |\$)"
}

getscript "sync.sh" >/dev/null && echo "sync.sh" $test_output >> outputfile.txt;
```

It works great but the output are all on one line.  It's not nicely indented like above.  How can I output it so it will be nicely indented?

tks

Comment: What's the reason for your `getscript` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man rsync` will show an option to log output to a logfile:

> **`--log-file=FILE`**
>   This  option  causes  `rsync`  to log what it is doing to a file.  This is similar to the logging
>   that a daemon does, but can be requested for the client  side  and/or  the  server  side  of  a
>   non-daemon  transfer.  If specified as a client option, transfer logging will be enabled with a
>   default format of `"%i %n%L"`.  See the `--log-file-format` option if you wish to override this.

Comment: Thank you roaima for the response.  So my code is
    rsync -aktvu --log-file=/scripts/web/output/outfile-sync.log -e 'ssh -p 22' --modify-window=1 --progress $SOURCE $USER@$SERVER:$DESTINATION
but when I included the --log-file=FILE it gives me an error.
    rsync: --log-file=/scripts/web/output/outfile-sync.log: unknown option
    rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1243) [client=2.6.8]
I checked the man pages but it doesn't include this option, --log-file.  I'm    using rsync  version 3.0.9.  I assume my rysnc does not have this option.  Is there a workaround??

Comment: Hmm. You seem to be using version 2.6.8 of `rsync`, which is so old all bets are off. It was _updated in November 2006_ so I'd recommend you get that fixed first. The security issues with a system running code that out of date hardly bear thinking about. Ugh!

Comment: I've updated my rsync and now I'm able to see the --log-file=FILE in the man page.  tks